# Biztalk CSV file - Calling Stored procedure

Tags: file, csv, biztalk

I have a requirement in that I receive CSV files from various sources with different formats. All the mappings are done in a SQL stored procedure. I would like to use the BizTalk to transfer the CSV files from SFTP locations to a local folder and inform SQL server that a file a received. Thus, from BizTalk I need to call a stored procedure only once per file. Not once for each line in the file. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you need to do anything with data in CSV file within BizTalk? Or just copy the file to a local folder and update SQL db?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal by using ths sql adapter.

-create a receive location when you receive files

-a stored procedure with an xml parameter to put within all the file content

-an orchestration where receive the message containing your csv file content

-from biztalk generate a schema to call your stored procedure with the content of your

Have a look on this sample : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms935658(v=bts.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you should use BizTalk here. all you need to do is load the csv file, pass its content to a sql sp.